# How to reduce APK size in Unity with Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

[enter image description here][1]I have created new Unity Project and imported Vuforia plugin from unity 2018.1
and when BUILD the APK the file size is **36MB**  with no assets.
When I make only ARMv7 and Stripping level: Use micro mscorlib the APK size is **18 MB.**

```
Build Report

Uncompressed usage by category:
Textures      0.0 kb    0.0% 
Meshes        0.0 kb     0.0% 
Animations    0.0 kb     0.0% 
Sounds        0.0 kb     0.0% 
Shaders       7.9 kb     0.0% 
Other Assets  1.6 kb     0.0% 
Levels        69.3 kb    0.1% 
Scripts       990.8 kb   1.5% 
Included DLLs 3.9 mb     5.9% 
File headers  16.3 kb    0.0% 
Complete size 66.6 mb    100.0%
```

**How come Complete Size is 66.6MB?????**

Answer (score 1):

The picture below isn't the newest but i think it explain itself

[image]

Comment: Is there any settings from which I can reduce the size of APK other than above settings